# What is the probability that two IID Bernoulli Processes have subsequences of length $i$ that agree?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm more of a physicist than a statistician, so forgive me if this is a basic question. I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around it.

We are given two IID Bernoulli Processes of length $n$ and probability of success $p$, that is, sequences $\{X_{j}\}_{j=1}^{n}$ and $\{Y_{j}\}_{j=1}^{n}$ such that $X_{j},Y_{j}\sim Bernoulli(p) \; \forall j$, and all R.V.s are independent. If we arrange the outcomes in ordered lists
$X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n} \; \text{and} \; Y_{1},Y_{2},...,Y_{n}$, I want to know the probability that the longest subsequences on which they agree is of length $i$. That is, subsequences $X_{p},X_{p+1},...,X_{p+i-1}$ and $Y_{q},Y_{q+1},...,Y_{q+i-1}$ on which $X_{p+k}=Y_{q+k}$ for all $1\leq k \leq i-1$ are the longest subsequences of this form, where $p$ is not necessarily equal to $q$. The answer should be a function of length $i \leq n$, of $n$, and of $p$ in complete generality.

To give an example, say our $X$ sequence is given by the list $0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1$ and our $Y$ sequence by $1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0$. Then, the last four outcomes of the $X$ process $0,1,0,1$ agree with the $2$nd to $5$th outcomes of the $Y$ process, and even though there are a couple of instances of length 3 subsequences which agree, the maximal length subsequence here would be 4.

What I am unsure about is whether this is just the same probability of 2 IID Bernoulli processes of length $i$ agreeing completely, in which case this isn't too hard. What is throwing me is whether the fact that the agreeing subsequences can start at arbitrary position - does this affect the probability? Would we have to sum over all starting positions for the subsequence?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are $(n+1-i)^2$ possible pairs of subsequences that might match and for each pair, the probbaility of a match is $2^{-i}$. Unfortunately, these are far from independent, but we can nevertheless conclude that the expected number of matches of length $i$ subsequences is $(n+1-i)^22^{-i}$  and this is an *upper bound* for the probability of at least one such match. In some cases this bound is $>1$ and hence trivial, but I'd wager that this bound is pretty good as soon as it is somewhat small-ish,

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that's a good start, thanks! Just a question - as the R.V.s are distributed $Bernoulli(p)$ and not $Bernoulli(1/2)$, shouldn't your '$2^{-i}$' be replaced with '$(1-2p(1-p))^{-i}$'?